# F Sharp convert list of tuples into list of mapped tuples

Tags: f#, functional-programming

Declare a function that converts a list of pairs to a Relation.

```
type Relation<'a,'b> = ('a * 'b list) list
```

Basically, turn this:

```
[(2,"c");(1,"a");(2,"b")]
```

into this:

```
[(2,["c";"b"]);(1,["a"])]
```

in this form:

```
toRel:(’a*’b) list -> Rel<’a,’b>
```

Any ideas? This isn't homework, just self-study and this one has me a bit stumped considering the form doesn't allow for accumulation.

Comment: `Seq.groupBy` does exactly this I think (or at least the hard part)

Comment: Already tried (`List.groupBy`) that and that kind of made it worse. While it's grouped properly, each value then also contains the key.

`[(2, [(2, "c"); (2, "b")]); (1, [(1, "a")])]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
[(2,"c");(1,"a");(2,"b")]
|> List.groupBy fst
|> List.map (fun (x,y)->x,List.map snd y)
```

Result:

```
[(2, ["c"; "b"]); (1, ["a"])]
```

Type inference is handy for the toRel bit:

```
let toRel xs = 
  xs
  |> List.groupBy fst
  |> List.map (fun (x,y)->x,List.map snd y)
```

Usage:

```
toRel [(2,"c");(1,"a");(2,"b")]
```

Comment: Oh, well... that was annoyingly simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can use various built-in functions and transformation to rebuild the behavior, but it is also good to have basic knowledge about recursion to build special functions from scratch.

Its also a good idea of doing this with recursion to learn to split a problem into more smaller problems to learn how to solve a bigger problem.

If you think in a recursive way, what you need todo is:

1. You remove the head of the list to get one element.
2. Then you create your tuple with the key and all values of the specified key
3. You remove all elements with they current key you processed and recurs on this list.
4. If you have an empty input list, your output is also empty.

So you start with:

```
let rec group list =
    if List.isEmpty list then []
    else
        ???
```

You remove the first element of a list with `List.head`. But we also want to
extract the tuple into its two components. You achieve this with

```
let k,v = List.head list
```

What we want to create is a new tuple that has the same key, but all values of the input list. We don't have that function yet, but we just assume we have a function `valuesOf` that we can pass a key and a list, and it just returns us all values of the defined key.

```
(k, (valuesOf k list))
```

In the first iteration of the input list you defined we would have `2` as `k` and we assume `valuesOf 2 list` returns `["b";"c"]`.

So the above code would return `(2, ["b";"c"])` as a value. Now the recursive call. We again assume we have a function `removeKey` that we can pass a key and a list and it returns a new list with all elements of the specified key removed.

```
(removeKey k list)
```

As an example

```
removeKey 2 [(1,"a");(2,"a");(2,"b");(3,"a")]
```

should return

```
[(1,"a");(3,"a")]
```

This new list that `removeKey` returns is the one you need to recurs on:

```
(group (removeKey k list))
```

You only have to put both pieces together. What you want to return is your new tuple with the recursive result.

```
(k, (valuesOf k list)) :: (group (removeKey k list))
```

and as one function.

```
let rec group list =
    if List.isEmpty list then []
    else
        let k,v = List.head list
        (k, (valuesOf k list)) :: group (removeKey k list)
```

We are not done yet, we still need to create `valuesOf` and `removeKey`.

```
let rec valuesOf key list =
    match list with
    | []      -> []
    | x::list ->
        let k,v = x
        if   k = key
        then v :: (valuesOf key list)
        else (valuesOf key list)
```

`valuesOf` uses Pattern Matching to deconstruct the list, instead of using `List.head` or `List.tail`. We just check if the element has the specified key. If it has we return the current value concatenated with the remaining list. Otherwise we just return the result of the recursive call and drop the current value.

`removeKey` is similar. We check if they key of a tuple matches, if yes we drop the whole element and just return the recursive call otherwise we return the current element with the recursive call.

```
let rec removeKey key list =
    match list with
    | []      -> []
    | x::list ->
        let k,v = x
        if   k = key
        then (removeKey key list)
        else x :: (removeKey key list)
```

and now we are done. Everything at once

```
let rec valuesOf key list =
    match list with
    | []      -> []
    | x::list ->
        let k,v = x
        if   k = key
        then v :: (valuesOf key list)
        else (valuesOf key list)

let rec removeKey key list =
    match list with
    | []      -> []
    | x::list ->
        let k,v = x
        if   k = key
        then (removeKey key list)
        else x :: (removeKey key list)

let rec group list =
    if List.isEmpty list then []
    else
        let k,v = List.head list
        (k, (valuesOf k list)) :: group (removeKey k list)

group [(2,"c");(1,"a");(2,"b");(2,"d");(3,"a");(1,"b")]
// returns: [(2, ["c"; "b"; "d"]); (1, ["a"; "b"]); (3, ["a"])]
```

The above functions are not tail-recursive. But you can re-write `valuesOf` and `removeKey` easily with `List.fold` or `List.foldBack`. Here I use `List.fold` as I assume it doesn't matter if the order of the elements changes.

```
let valuesOf key list =
    List.fold (fun acc (k,v) ->
        if k = key
        then v :: acc
        else acc
    ) [] list

let removeKey key list =
    List.fold (fun acc (k,v) ->
        if   k = key
        then acc
        else (k,v) :: acc
    ) [] list
```

`group` cannot easily re-written with `List.fold` or `List.foldBack` because we need access to the whole list. But it is still not hard to achieve tail-recursion.

```
let group list =
    let rec loop result list =
        if List.isEmpty list then result
        else
            let k,v = List.head list
            loop
                ((k, (valuesOf k list)) :: result)
                (removeKey k list)
    loop [] list
```

If you don't expect to have lists with thousands or more key,value pairs then you also can keep the non tail-recursive functions.

Even if it feels good to create smaller code with already provided functions like `List.groupBy` and `List.map` you should be able to create such kind of recursive functions yourself. Why?

An immutable linked list is a recursive defined data-structure and working with recursive functions is only natural. If you don't know how to create such functions yourself you run into trouble the moment you create your own recursive data-structures, because then you have zero pre-defined functions like `groupBy` and `map` you already can use. You must build those functions yourself.

Trying to rebuild the function defined in the `List` module or things like you described here are actually good ways of training that you should do yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Given that each key only occurs once you could also do:

```
[(2,"c");(1,"a");(2,"b")]
|> List.fold (fun (m:Map<int, string>) (k, v) -> m.Add (k, v))
             Map.empty
```

If a key occurs more than once the last value would be kept.